# Unable to differentiate $\arctan\bigl( \frac x{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\bigr)$

Tags: derivatives

Im unable to differentiate $\arctan \Bigl(\frac{x}{ \sqrt {a^2-x^2}}\Bigr)$

What I did:
I substituted $x$ with $a\sin t$

as a result of which I got $\arctan(\tan t)=t=\arcsin {x\over a}$

The answer which I got:$a\over \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$

The answer given in the book $1\over \sqrt{a^2-x^2}$

Please tell me what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have possibly forgotten to use the fact that

> $$\frac d{dx}\bigg(\frac x a\bigg) = \frac 1 a$$

Now $a$ from numerator and denominator will **get cancelled** provided that $a>0$ else you will also have $\text{sgn}(a)$.

Comment: Yeah got it thanks

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{cases}\left(\arctan x\right)'=\cfrac1{1+x^2}\\{}\\
\left(\cfrac x{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)'=\cfrac{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}-x\frac{-x}{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}}{a^2-x^2}=\cfrac{a^2-x^2+x^2}{\left(a^2-x^2\right)^{3/2}}=\cfrac{a^2}{\left(a^2-x^2\right)^{3/2}}\end{cases}$$$${}$$

so applying the Chain Rule, the one you seem you have forgotten:$${}$$

$$\left(\arctan\frac x{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}\right)'=\frac1{1+\frac{x^2}{a^2-x^2}}\cdot\frac{a^2}{\left(a^2-x^2\right)^{3/2}}=\require{cancel}\frac{\cancel{a-x^2}}{\cancel{a^2}}\cdot\frac{\cancel{a^2}}{\left(a^2-x^2\right)^{\cancel{3/2}}}=$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}$$